How to pass props with SolidJS Router?
I recently build a small SPA with SolidJS. While building the basic setup was easy and straightforward, I now run more and more into problems while implementing functionality. Can someone explain how the Solid-Router passes down props? I tried different ways, but none worked. My code now looks like that:
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { Router, Route } from "@solidjs/router";
import "./app.css";

function Header(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>{props.name}</div>
      <div>Test</div>
    </>
  );
}

function App() {
  let name = "Test Val";

  return (
    <>
      <Route path="/test" component={Header} props={{ name }}></Route>
    </>
  );
}

render(
  () => (
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  ),
  document.getElementById("app")
);

Running the code without the Router works fine. With the Router the props don't get displayed.
I read the docs from bottom to top and also asked AI. But for a beginners the documentation is not very helpful... and the AI solutions don't work either.

Router is designed to operate against routes. It listens for route changes, captures paths and query parameters and display results. In other words, the user visits URLs and see the matching paths and properties.
So, passing explicit values to a router is against the idea of routes. You should let the user visit a path with query parameters and show results accordingly.
So instead of explicit values you should use:

Paths
Match Filters
Query Parameters

Here is some examples:
/users

/users?limit=30

/user/:id

/user/:id/posts

/user/:id/post/:id

/user/:id/post/:id?/

Please see this link for more: https://github.com/solidjs/solid-router?tab=readme-ov-file#router-primitives
PS: I do not think your app will for SPA out of the box. You should either use a hash mode router or modify your server to server the same page for all paths. Otherwise you will have page not found errors on refresh.

https://github.com/solidjs/solid-router?tab=readme-ov-file#hash-mode-router
https://github.com/solidjs/solid-router?tab=readme-ov-file#spas-in-deployed-environments

Here is an example showing how to use all of these:
import { A, Route, RouteSectionProps, Router, useParams, useSearchParams } from '@solidjs/router';
import { Component, Index, createEffect } from 'solid-js';
import { render } from 'solid-js/web';

const Users = () => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams<any>();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Users</h1>
      <Index
        fallback={<div>Fetch and display all users here!</div>}
        each={Array.from({ length: searchParams.limit || 0 })}
      >
        {(item, index) => (
          <li><A href={`/user/${index}`}>Visit User #{index}</A></li>
        )}
      </Index>
    </div>
  )
};

const User = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  console.log({...params})
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>User {params.id}</h1>
      <div>Fetch and display user details here!</div>
    </div>
  )
};

const Home = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  createEffect(() => console.log(params));
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <div>Here comes the content of the home component!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};


const App: Component<RouteSectionProps<unknown>> = props => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  
  const handleClick = () => {
    setSearchParams({ limit: 20 });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
        <li><A href="/user/id">User #1</A></li>
        <li><A href='/users/'>Users</A></li>
        <div><A href="/users?limit=10">Users with limit={10}</A></div>
      </ul>
      <div><button onClick={handleClick}>Set Limit to 20</button></div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}

render(() => (
  <Router root={App}>
    <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
    <Route path="/user/:id" component={User} />
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
  </Router>
), document.body);


Thanks (again) for the answer. It seems that I dont quite get the idea behind SolidJS. For my SPA I do use the Hashrouter. But thats not the case. To put it in another way: how do I get props into my components, when they are inside of a Router? In my example props act as supposed (and in a way the docs tell me), when the component is on its own. When the compinent is inside a Router props dont work. Same goes for refs...

@kjh I added an example. It will clarify your confusion.
